# How do I read in a CLOB column that's too large to fit in a string?

Tags: php, sql

I have an Oracle SQL database with a CLOB column that holds a great deal of data.  I'm running into the issue that a regular PHP string variable will not hold all of the data that I have in the CLOB column. It will only read in 4618 bits, but my file is much larger. The CLOB column has a series of IP addresses in it. What I need to do is parse the CLOB column so I can extract those IP addresses; however, the string variable won't hold enough data to even get to the portion of the document where the IP addresses are stored. Any thoughts?

Comment: I have a feeling you should be storing your IPs in a separate table with a foreign key pointing back to the original table.

Comment: There is no limit on the length of string in PHP (other than system memory, or memory_limit).  Are you getting an error message?

Comment: Well, when I do this and try to echo $ipAddr, the page loads fine, with only a portion of the file shown:

$ipAddr = $clob->read(700);

However, when I do this, the page does not load:

$ipAddr = $clob->read($clob->size());

I'll get the following error message then:

XML Parsing Error: not well-formed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments:

If you right click in your browser and say "view source" you'll see that you indeed have the entire file.

Most likely you just need to set the appropriate ContentType when emitting the data back to the browser.

Comment: Well, the contentType is XML, and the string is embedded in an XML tag.  Should I be doing something differently?

Comment: @stix122: probably.  I often see browsers complain about a file not being compliant XML when, IMHO, it is.  You might look at the following to see if it helps resolve your actual issue http://mycodetrip.com/2007/03/26/fix-for-xml-parsing-error-not-well-formed-line-number-1-column-2-error_36/

Answer (score 0):

First, try increasing the PHP memory limit to see if that has any effect on the error.  If the CLOB object being retrieved is truly huge, like 2 GiB, then there is no way (currently) to process it in PHP since the whole object must be held in memory.

If the column has fixed length data, it should be fairly easy to compose an appropriate query which extracts a portion of it.  Assuming the data is encoded as fixed-length text, then something like this will work:

```
// assumes subfield is xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:  19 fixed characters
SELECT substr (TO_CHAR(gnarly_ipadddress_fieldname), 1, 19) as ipaddr1,
       substr (TO_CHAR(gnarly_ipadddress_fieldname), 20, 19) as ipaddr2,
       substr (TO_CHAR(gnarly_ipadddress_fieldname), 39, 19) as ipaddr3
FROM table
WHERE (whatever);
```

If the subfields are variable length, then maybe grabbing something like 16K chunks and parsing it in PHP is the way to go.