# Can't read CLOB into string... sometimes

Tags: php, sql

I have an array of CLOB datatypes.  In my sample data, there are two items in the array.  The array is embedded in a FOR loop that will loop until all of the data is read from the array (in this case, twice).  I have a function that reads the CLOB data into a string, then returns the string, literally just:

```
function getCLOB($clob)
{
   $str = $clob->read($clob->size());
   return $str;
}
```

My problem is that it reads in the first thing I send it fine and I can get that to display back in the FOR loop.  However, when I send the second one, the string is empty.  I put in some echos to see what was happening with the data and the `$clob` variable has data once it's in the function, but the `$str` variable is empty after the first line of the function.  Does anyone have any ideas on why it works once but not the second time?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I read in a CLOB column that's too large to fit in a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7587567/how-do-i-read-in-a-clob-column-thats-too-large-to-fit-in-a-string)

Comment: No, this is a different problem.  The two items in the array are the same size, so it would be odd that one could be read into a string easily and the other could not.

Comment: Maybe if You can add Your loop somebody will be able to help You. :)